# Specifying multiple Twilio numbers when sending an SMS to spread load over all numbers

Tags: twilio

I am new to Twilio and was reading that the limit is 1 SMS per Second per Number.

If you have more phone numbers, then the overall sending rate increases.

My question is if we need to specify multiple numbers in the code in order to take advantage of the increased rate with having more numbers, or is this taken care of automatically by Twilio, even when I specify only one number in the code?

It is not clear if I manually have to Round Robin across all my numbers myself, or if Twilio does this for us.

I am using PHP to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

You will have to write the code that round robins across all of the numbers in your account.  This should be pretty straight-forward.

What I would do is put all of those numbers in an array (you can use the REST API to get the [list of all of your Twilio phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list)), and then in your message sending loop, just use a counter to keep track of your place in that array.  Once that counter reaches the array size, just reset it to 0 to start over at the beginning of the array.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years the answer to this question has changed. There is now a Twilio service called [Copilot](https://www.twilio.com/copilot) which enables all kinds of number intelligence. See the [docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot) for examples of how to use it. That docs page lists it as a "public beta" (though it also suggests sending API queries to the 2010 version of their API, so it seems a bit outdated).

**Edit:** Be sure to read the docs regarding the response, since the Copilot behavior is different than the standard message sending behavior:

> There is a slight difference in API response when specifying the MessagingServiceSid parameter. When you only specify the *From* parameter, Twilio will validate the phone numbers synchronously and return either a **queued** status or an error. When specifying the *MessagingServiceSid* parameter, Twilio will first return an **accepted** status.